# Moving divs in mobile view with Bootstrap offsets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following set of divs:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-5" id="left">
    <div id="A"></div>
    <br />
    <div id="B"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-5" id="right">
    <div id="C"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So we have a left and right column, with the left column containing two divs and the right column containing one. JSFiddle doesn't seem to have Bootstrap as an option so I had to make do.

What I want to achieve, when in mobile view, is this:

[image]

You can see the div that was at the top left, div A, is now at the bottom. I know I need to use offsets for this, but my tinkering has produced no results.

Comment: You can use bootstrap in jsfiddle. See my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/9YB6S/1/).

Comment: So you are attempting to move div A to the bottom of the other two divs in mobile view?